# Do illuminated/glowing enemies grant advantage automatically?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, advantage-and-disadvantage

Pretty straight forward. I couldn't find any rules on this so I thought I'd ask the internet.

If an enemy is glowing for any reason (torch, spell effect, etc.) do you automatically give attackers against them advantage?

Answer (score 16):

## No

Magically highlighting targets to grant advantage when attacking them is the specific effect of [Faerie Fire](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/faerie-fire), so it should not be the general case for "carrying a light source".